# How could I get this regex statment to capture just a select piece

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to get the regex in this loop,

```
my $vmsn_file = $snapshots{$snapshot_num}{"filename"};
my @current_vmsn_files = $ssh->capture("find -name $vmsn_file");
foreach my $vmsn (@current_vmsn_files) {
$vmsn =~ /(.+\.vmsn)/xm;
print "$1\n";
}
```

to capture the filename from this line,

```
./vmfs/volumes/4cbcad5b-b51efa39-c3d8-001517585013/MX01/MX01-Snapshot9.vmsn
```

The only part I want is the part is the actual filename, not the path.

I tried using an expression that was anchored to the end of the line using `$` but that did not seem to make any difference. I also tried using 2 `.+` inputs, one before the capture group and the one inside the capture group. Once again no luck, also that felt kinda messy to me so I don't want to do that unless I must.

Any idea how I can get at just the file name after the last `/` to the end of the line?

More can be added as needed, I am not sure what I needed to post to give enough information.

--Update--

With 5 minutes of tinkering I seemed to have figured it out. (what a surprise)

So now I am left with this, (and it works)

```
my $vmsn_file = $snapshots{$snapshot_num}{"filename"};
my @current_vmsn_files = $ssh->capture("find -name $vmsn_file");
foreach my $vmsn (@current_vmsn_files) {
$vmsn =~ /.+\/(\w+\-Snapshot\d+\.vmsn)/xm;
print "$1\n";
}
```

Is there anyway to make this better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best way is using the core module [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html).  That will make your code most portable.

If you really want to do it with a regex and you are based on Unix, then you could use:

```
$vmsn =~ m%.*/([^/]+)$%;
$file = $1;
```

Comment: I am on Ubuntu Linux, will this method work if the filename is captured using SSH. This script queries my server for the filename(s) in the first place.

Comment: nitpick: I don't thing the `[^/]` is necessary since the first `.*` is greedy.

Comment: @Solignis: if you have a file name in a string, it will work.  It doesn't matter where it was captured from.

Comment: Ah ok, I was thinking it only if the file was locally available or something.

Comment: I have never seen the % used in regex what does it do?

Comment: @Solignis It's not a part of the regex. It's the envelope. In many cases, it's a slash before and after the regex. In this case it's a percentage.

Comment: @Solignis It is not part of the regex, it is part of the match *operator*. If you leave off the "m" part of the match operator (//) then you must use slash as the delimiter. If you specify the "m" part (m//) then you can use an alternate delimiter, eg m##, m!!, m%%. Jonathan used it so that the slash that really is in the regex would not need to be backslashed.

Answer (score 1):

well, if you are going to use `find` command from the shell, and considering you stated that you only want the file name, why not

```
... $ssh->capture("find -name $vmsn_file -printf \"%f\n\" ");
```

If not, the simplest way is to `split()` your string on `"/"` and then get the last element. No need regular expressions that are too long or complicated.

See `perldoc -f split` for more information on usage